# Django | Custom INSERT SQL con TRANSACTION

Tags: python, django

Tratando de hacer una INSERT Sql en Django, me pide que **"query_list"** debe tener un contenido ¿Qué contenido? Que yo sepa (puedo estar confundido), la query suele contener conexión + consulta. También dice que query tiene un error de sintaxis.
Gracias.

**View.py**

```
from django.db import connection,transaction
def saveUserAnswer(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        prueba = request.POST['name']
        #Hacer la insert SQL
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        query = INSERT INTO testapp_useranswers (modality) VALUES (prueba);
        query_list = build_query_list()        
        cursor.executemany(query, query_list)
        transaction.commit()
```

Error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Nunca he utilizado raw queries, siempre utilizo los modelos de django. Intenta colocar la consulta INSERT entre comillas. `“INSERT INTO...”`, o entre triple comillas si la separas en varias líneas.

Comment: ¿Intercalando o concatenando la variable prueba? Un saludo.

Comment: Responderé la pregunta para poder poner ejemplos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Debes importar el módulo de conexión:
from django.db import connection

# Obtienes el objeto cursor:
cursor = connection.cursor()
# Preparas la consulta SQL para luego reemplazar los datos que desees insertar:
query = ''' 
                INSERT INTO testapp_useranswers (modality) 
                VALUES (%s) 
         '''
# Ejecutas la query. Aquí reemplazamos la variable que necesitamos para nuestro INSERT en forma de lista
cursor.execute(query, [prueba])

# Puedes usar el commit como ya lo tienes
```

De esta manera puedes insertar usando una consulta en modo `raw`.